# Why is my for loop not working in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I tried to load data into my template using for loop ended up getting the for loop tags written on my template.

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from projet.models import Employe
# Create your views here.

def page(request) : 
    employe = Employe.objects.all()
    return render(request,'hello.html',{'employe':employe})
```

Html table template

```
     <table class="table">

            <tr class="tr">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nom et Prenom</th>
                <th>Lundi</th>
                <th>Mardi</th>
                <th>Mercredi</th>
                <th>Jeudi</th>
                <th>Vendredi</th>
                <th>Samedi</th>
                <th>Dimanche</th>
            </tr>

            { % for i in employe % }
              <tr>
                <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.monday }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.tuesday }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.wednesday }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.thursday }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.friday }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.saturday }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.sunday }}</td>

              </tr>
            { % endfor % }
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have spaces between your { and your %.

```
{% for i int ... %}
.....
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It kinda looks like this may have been done automatically by a linter, so OP may want to turn off html linting temporarily or use something that recognises django templates ...